# zxing in C# using IKVM

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing

I converted the jar file into .net dll file using IKVM. Now i am trying to consume it in my .net app, but it seems that the qrcodereader.decode requires BinaryBitmap which further requires Luminance as parameter. Please guide me in this situation since i couldn't find the right classes that implements the abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

Luminance sources are platform specific. You can find examples in the android, java2se, and iphone directories. I don't know if there are any luminance sources in the csharp directory but that code is not actively maintained so even if there is, it'll likely take cleanup adaptation (not to mention I have no idea if it's compatible with IKVM).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. RGBLuminanceSource class inherits the LuminanceSource class in c# but i encounter a exception when i decode some QRCodes which is decoded perfectly in Zxingorg website. Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: Sorry, but no. It sounds like there's the need for some hard core debugging.